# Generating PEM code from DER code for RSA public key

Tags: base64, rsa, pem, der

I have asn.1 code

```
RSAPublicKey ::= SEQUENCE {
modulus           INTEGER,  7120255303029382831
publicExponent    INTEGER   4242026487
}
```

I encoded asn.1 code with DER

```
30 11 02 08 62 D0 3A 79 2F 28 5E AF 02 05 00 FC D8 02 FF 07
```

I encoded DER code with base64(I'm trying to generate PEM code)

```
MzAgMTEgMDIgMDggNjIgRDAgM0EgNzkgMkYgMjggNUUgQUYgMDIgMDUgMDAgRkMgRDggMDIgRkYgMDc
```

But when I try to encrypt something with it it says 'Error: Too few bytes to read ASN.1 value.' in cyberchef.

What should I do please help me with how it.

Comment: Show. The. Code.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk what code?

Comment: This is a website for programming questions, you seem to have a programming problem so we need to see the code for the program you wrote.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I didn't write any code just I encoded some variables in  https://asn1.io/asn1playground/ and https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=To_Base64('A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D')&input=MzAgMTEgMDIgMDggNjIgRDAgM0EgNzkgMkYgMjggNUUgQUYgMDIgMDUgMDAgRkMgRDggMDIgRkYgMDcK